# os.rename module raises WindowsError, don't understand why

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

Here is a snippet of code.

```
import os
def rename_files():
file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Oleg\Desktop\prank\prank")
print (file_list)
saved_path = os.getcwd()
print("Current Working Directory Is "+saved_path)
for x in file_list:
    print x
    x1 = x.translate(None,"0123456789")
    print x1
    os.rename(x, x1)
rename_files()`
```

The problem is that it is giving me an error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/rename_files.py", line 13, in <module>
rename_files()
File "C:/Python27/rename_files.py", line 11, in rename_files
os.rename(x, x1)
WindowsError: [Error 2] ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????
```

Comment: Open an elevated terminal and rerun your script.

Comment: perhaps the file is open in another program?

Comment: Does it literally print a bunch of question marks?

Comment: What are `x` and `x1`?

Comment: Yes, it does print a bunch of question marks. None of the files are open in any other program. What do you guys think the problem might be?

Comment: @Galen: They're both defined in the code.

Comment: x is every element of the array, x1 is every element of the array with some characters removed from it.

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: This is the error...

Comment: user3503816: @Galen may have meant what are their value is this specific case of failure.

Comment: I think the problem is `os.listdir()` returns a file list, but it's just a list of file names, not complete paths. You'll need to us `os.path.join()` to concatenate the the directory to each file name. An alternative what would give you full path names would be to use `glob.glob()`.

Comment: Those question marks in an English-language locale would be "The system cannot find the file specified". Apparently the localized error message can't be displayed properly with the console's default OEM codepage. Upgrade to Python 3.6 or install and enable  the `win_unicode_console` package to support Unicode in the Windows console instead of legacy codepages.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the path you're listing when renaming the files, try with:

```
import os

def rename_files(path):
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    print(file_list)
    for x in file_list:
        print(x)
        x1 = x.translate(None,"0123456789")
        print(x1)
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, x), os.path.join(path, x1))

rename_files(r"C:\Users\Oleg\Desktop\prank\prank")
```